# Pin Request on BLE Connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In Native Android I'm trying to connect to a BLE Device.

I'm using the setPin() function and it works.
However, I still see the dialog and keyboard pop for user input of the pin:

"Bluetooth pairing request Enter PIN to pair the device."

I've tried various solutions I've found here on SO and elsewhere but have had no luck.

It will either pop up and stay until "Cancel" is hit or you tap outside the prompt or sometimes it will pop up only for a split second before disappearing.
But either way the device is already connected and functional.

Any ideas on how to properly suppress this dialog would be much appreciated!

```
  private BroadcastReceiver pairing_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST")) {
            //Log.d(filter, name + ": PAIRING_REQUEST");

            // must call this function to trigger a PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN callback
            if (!device.setPairingConfirmation(true)) { Log.d(APP_TAG, "ERROR: setPairingConfirmation"); }

            int type = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN) {
                //Log.d(filter, name + ": PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN");
                if (!device.setPin(pin())) { Log.d(APP_TAG, name + ": ERROR setPin"); }

            } else if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION) {
                //Log.d(filter, name + ": PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION");

            } else {
                //Log.d(filter, name + ": UNKNOWN PAIRING TYPE = " + type);
            }

        } else {
            //Log.d(filter, name + ": UNKNOWN PAIRING ACTION");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you stepped though the debugger and identified exactly where the dialog pops up?

Comment: It appears to be happening when setPin is called. Which doesn't make sense since, this should be the method preventing it?

Comment: Admittedly, I have never done this, but I am thinking that `setPairingConfirmation` is causing the issue. In all the examples I have seen `setPairingConfirmation` and `setPin` have been called independently and not one after the other like here ::  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/froyo/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/BluetoothPairingDialog.java

Comment: An interesting note: I made a change to the above to match the implementation in the link. That is, I moved 'setPairingConfirmation' to the else if of 'PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION' and removed the original so it is only called within that else if. And the result was behavior unchanged, that it still connects with no issue but the dialog appears and disappears.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help more, but as I mentioned I have never done this before. Hope you find a solution. Good Luck!